# How to use mousePressed with 2D array

Tags: processing

I'm new to processing and programming in general and I'm having issues getting the mousePressed function to have the desired effect. I'd appreciate some assistance or advice on getting it to work as intended.

```
int[][] cave;
int caveSize = 50;

int PILLAR =  1;
int FIX  = -1;
int EMPTY = -2;
int MINE = 2;

color pillar   = color(255, 255, 255);
color mine   = color(255, 0, 0);
color fix    = color(0, 255, 0);
color empty   = color(0, 0, 0);

boolean end  = false;

void setup() {
    size(602, 352);   
    stroke(100);
    noSmooth();

    cave = new int[width/caveSize][height/caveSize];
    for(int x=0; x < width/caveSize; x++) {
        for(int y=0; y< height/caveSize; y++) {
            cave[x][y] = 0;
        }
    } 
    placePoints();
}

void draw() {   
    background(color(0, 0, 0));

    for (int x=0; x < width/caveSize; x++) {
        for (int y=0; y < height/caveSize; y++) {
           if(cave[x][y] == PILLAR) {
             fill(pillar);  
           } 
            if(cave[x][y] == MINE) {
             fill(mine);
           }
           if (cave[x][y] == FIX) { 
             fill(fix);
           } 
           if (cave[x][y] == EMPTY) { 
             fill(empty);
           }
           rect(x*caveSize, y*caveSize, caveSize, caveSize);
           noFill();
       } 
   } 


   if (end) {
       textSize(50);
       fill(255);
       text("GAME OVER!", width/4, height/2); 
       noFill();
   }
}

void mousePressed()
{
 // int x = mouseX/8;
 // int y = mouseY/8;

  if(mouseX == PILLAR && mouseY == PILLAR)
  {
   fill(fix); 
  }
  if(mouseX == MINE && mouseY == MINE)
  {
   fill(mine); 
  }
  else
  {


  }



}

boolean game_over() {
     for(int x=0; x < width/caveSize; x++) {
        for(int y=0; y< height/caveSize; y++) {
            if (cave[x][y] == PILLAR || cave[x][y] == MINE) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    end = true;
    return true;
}




void end() {
    if (game_over()) {
        return;   
    }
}

void placePoints() {   



    cave[3][1] = MINE;
    cave[7][2] = MINE;
    cave[2][3] = MINE;
    cave[9][4] = MINE;
    cave[1][5] = MINE;
    cave[6][4] = MINE;
    cave[4][5] = MINE;
    cave[6][3] = MINE;
    cave[5][5] = MINE;
    cave[7][6] = MINE;
    cave[0][2] = MINE;
    cave[1][0] = MINE;
    cave[10][1] = MINE;
    cave[11][3] = MINE;
    cave[11][6] = MINE;   
    cave[6][4] = MINE;
    cave[4][5] = MINE;
    cave[6][3] = MINE;
    cave[5][5] = MINE;
    cave[7][6] = MINE;   

    cave[5][6] = PILLAR;
    cave[6][6] = PILLAR;
    cave[3][6] = PILLAR;
    cave[4][6] = PILLAR;

    cave[5][2] = PILLAR;
    cave[5][3] = PILLAR;
    cave[5][4] = PILLAR;

    cave[0][0] = PILLAR;
    cave[0][1] = PILLAR;   

    cave[11][2] = PILLAR;
    cave[10][2] = PILLAR;
    cave[9][2] = PILLAR;
}
```

Basically what I want to to click on a square to check for a condition and change the square's colour, similar to a form of 'Battleships' game. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2):

mouseX/mouseY is the pixel X/y position of the mouse. To determine on which square it is, you have to divide the pixel position by the square width/height. Use this as parameters of the 2D array to find the right square. Then you have to check/assign the changed value to that square.

Something like this:

```
void mousePressed()
{
  int x = mouseX/caveSize;
  int y = mouseY/caveSize;

  if (cave[x][y] == PILLAR) //if the value is PILLAR (=1)
  {
    cave[x][y] = FIX; //set the value to FIX (=-1)
  }
  if (cave[x][y] == MINE) //if the value is MINE (=2)
  {
    cave[x][y] = MINE;  //set the value to MINE (=2) (the same??)
  } 
}
```

On the next frame the square will have its new color.